# Django, настройка соединения с PostgeSQL в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, postgresql

Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, Python 3.5.2, PostgreSQL 11.5

Никак не удается настроить соединение Django+PostgeSQL.
На более низком уровне проблема с библиотекой psycopg2.

Создал отдельный файл "psycopg2_test.py":

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres'")
```

На все мои попытки что-то изменить, получаю неизменное: psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres".

Сервер PostgreSQL работает, о чем свидетельствует вывод команды "systemctl status postgresql.service" + к базе есть доступ с помощью утилиты psql.

Any help

Comment: ну, СУБД работает и прямым текстом отвечает: вы указали неправильный пароль. Скорей всего у postgres пользователя нет пароля вовсе, если сами его не меняли.

Comment: У PostgreSQL пользователя 'postgres' пароль 'postgres', а у пользователя операционной системы 'postgres' пароля судя по всему нет

Comment: unix пользователь здесь без разницы. А СУБД не согласна что пароль пользователя `postgres`. Посмотрите на rolpassword в pg_authid. Если пароль пользователя postgres указан как postgres - то в поле будет `md53175bce1d3201d16594cebf9d7eb3f9d`

Comment: Значение rolpassword в pg_authid действительно md53175bce1d3201d16594cebf9d7eb3f9d

Comment: А база вообще та? Покажите `pg_lsclusters`

Comment: Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
11  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log

Comment: Выполнил и вижу, что порт почему-то 5433

Comment: просят перенести обсуждение в чат

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98273/discussion-between-mynick-and-).

Comment: Ну собственно ошибка потому что вы подключаетесь не к той базе.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Если напишите ответ, обязательно выберу его лучшим